# What is the correct way to use exceptions with PHP?

Tags: php, exception

I have always the "return status code" method to manage errors. It seems that exceptions are nowdays the best formed way to manage errors.
But are they really the best way ? I have read stuff like [exceptions are worst than GoTo](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html)

Do you know some good articles/posts/books about exceptions and error management?

Comment: This topic comes up once in a while. You will find some enlightening answers in the search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20exceptions%20vs%20errors and probably some explanation that's relevant to your case (= there is no one correct way for everything).

Comment: Would this question be a better fit on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), or is it still too broad?

Answer (score 4):

If you program object orientated, maybe exceptions are better for you. If you write procedural, return values are the better way. It depends on your coding style etc.

Comment: because nothing is worse than inconsistence. Exceptions are an object orientated pattern, return codes come from procedural programming.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are about 10000x slower than returning a status/error code depending on the programming language.  This is due to all the stack information being kept track of.  That's the bad.

In general, you don't ever have to use exceptions.  In fact, at one point, the only thing that existed was return codes.

The nice thing about exceptions is that they won't let a program continue unless they are dealt with correctly.  Instead, the program crashes.

So, basically, if you are forgetful about handling status messages or are worried that others may not check return codes from your functions, exceptions stop the program and make you fix it.  Although, I have seen a lot of inexperienced programmers catch the exception, not do anything about it, and then continue on.  This is basically the same as ignoring the return code from a function.

One other nice thing about exceptions is that they "bubble up" automatically.  Instead of having to pass back error codes through a long chain of functions, you could set up your try catch at the very top level and handle any error appropriately (assuming you didn't want anything else to happen in between).  For example, if anything goes wrong, display an error page.